# Is there any other ways to accomplish this task in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, hashmap

This might be a silly question, but I was wondering if I could accomplish this task using a dictionary or some sort of array? I tried using a dictionary like this, and it just calls all functions.

My goal is to call a specific function if a keyword is input by the user, but I want to avoid using those lengthy if and else statements.

Here is what I have tried:

```
def Func1():
    print ("This is func1")

def Func2():
    print ("This is func2")

def Func3():
    print ("This is func3")

functions = {"/func1" : Func1(), "/func2" : Func2(), "/func3" : Func3()}
```

Comment: you can leave function objects, without calling them

Comment: I would have to create so many objects though right? Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary that contains the function *objects* but does not actually *call* them:

```
def func1():
    print("I am function 1")

# etc for func2 and func3

functions = {
    "func1": func1,
    "func2": func2,
    "func3": func3
}
answer = input("Which function do you want to call? ")
if answer in functions:
    # find the correct function object and call it
    functions[answer]()
else:
    print("I can't find that function.")
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot simpler way to do it is just to look up the function corresponding to the command that the user gives

```py
def Func1():
    print ("This is func1")

def Func2():
    print ("This is func2")

def Func3():
    print ("This is func3")

functions = {"/func1" : Func1, "/func2" : Func2, "/func3" : Func3}
user_input = input("Enter command> ")
functions[user_input]()
```

Also make sure to remove the parenthesis from the functions stored in the dictionary or they will execute when the script is ran.